# Prime value in sequence

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

For the question, stated below I am unable to use the provided hint (stated after the question). I feel that this hint is used for proving that there are an infinite number of primes, and do not know how to use it for given question.

Let $p_k$ denote the $kth$ prime. Show that

$p_{n+1} \le p_1p_2p_3...p_n +1$, for all $n \ge 1.$

Hint: Let $N = p_1p_2p_3...p_n +1.$ A prime factor of $N$ must be at least as large as $p_{n+1}$.

---

Also, I have doubt in the given hint if (as usually is done) used for proving infinite number of primes are there. The reason is sometimes it may fail too.
E.g., for the below examples (although in the first example, I have started from $p_2$, i.e. 3) :

i) $3\times5 + 1 = 16$

ii) $2\times3\times5\times7\times11\times13 + 1 = 30031 = 59\times509$

Comment: The hint simply says that $N$ cannot have a prime factor $p\le p_n$ because we assume that $p_1,p_2,\cdots ,p_n$ is the complete list of the primes. The addition of $1$ ensures that none of the primes $p_1,\cdots,p_n$ divides $N$. However, $N$ must have a prime factor, giving the desired contradiction. The prime factors of $N$ must exceed $p_n$, so the hint is absolutely correct. And of course, you have to use all the primes upto $p_n$, the example $3\cdot 5+1=16$ is not a valid counter-example.

Comment: The basic idea of the proof remains the same if we omit primes. If we assume that $3$ and $5$ are all the primes, we get another prime, namely $2$ via $3\cdot 5+1=16=2^4$, but usually we assume that we have the complete list of primes upto $p_n$

Comment: @Peter So, omission of any prime(s) in the sequence is not an issue? I mean that only the sequence has to be followed for increasing primes, and there can be any omission of primes in the list given.

Comment: To guarantee to get a prime larger than all given primes, you need all the primes upto $p_n$, if you only want to get another (which is enough to show that the list cannot be complete), you do not. So, Euclid's idea (proving that no list of primes can be complete) also works in the case of missing primes upto $p_n$ , but usually , we assume that no primes upto $p_n$ are missing. And the given hint also assumes that.

Comment: @Peter Please refer to some source for more info. about your last comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you say that it fails? The fourth prime is $7$ and $7\leqslant16$.

Let $p$ the smallest prime factor of $p_1p_2\ldots p_n+1$. Then $p\leqslant p_1p_2\ldots p_n+1$. Besides, $p\neq p_k$, for each $k\in\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$. Therefore $p_{n+1}=p\leqslant p_1p_2\ldots p_n+1$.

Answer (score 0):

$N$ is not necessarily a prime. However, for $i = 1, \ldots , n$, $N \equiv 1 \, (mod \, p_i)$, so that $p_i$ doesn't divide $N$. Therefore the least prime divisor of $N$ is $p_k$ where $k > n$.

Comment: According to my understanding, to add to your answer, the last line can be amended to make it more complete, as below: Therefore the least prime divisor of $N$ is $p_k$ where $k \gt n$, if $N$ is a prime.

Comment: My earlier comment needs completion by an example for a composite value of $N = 16$, as in case i) of OP. In this case, the least prime divisor is 2, as it does not satisfy the condition for $N$ being a prime.

Comment: Adding further to your answer : The failure is wrong term to use in OP for the two cases, as in ii) 59 is a new prime "not-in-the-list" of primes whose product is formed. Similarly, for 509. Even am able to get a new prime factor of 2 in i), as $16 = 2^4$. So, $N$ being a composite does not matter at all. What matters is the factorization of N (if composite) leads to new primes.